# VelocityEngineUtils has been removed in Spring 3.2 so what else to use?

Tags: java, spring, velocity

Today I have upgraded my entire Spring web application from using Spring `3.1.1` to Spring `3.2`.

Most part of my existing app does not break except that in Spring `3.2`, the

```
org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineUtils
```

class seems to be removed completely from the **spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar**.

I found the migration guide as in [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/migration-3.2.html) url.

It stated that `org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineUtils` class has just been deprecated, but in fact it has been removed completely.

Maybe I'm just mistaken, I would like to know if the VelocityEngineUtils class still exist in somewhere or if not, what is the alternative class that I can use.

**EDIT:** It seems the entire velocity package has been removed from Spring `3.2` so now even 
`org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean` does not exist. Are Spring walking away from Velocity?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think `VelocityEngineUtils` was in the `spring-context` jar (at least not since Spring last 3.1.x releases, according to GitHub).

Anyway, you can find it in `spring-context-support-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar`

Comment: The velocity classes were once in the spring-context.jar and my code relied on that. Anyway thank for your quick reply :)

Comment: @woraphol.j You must have had some very odd mix of spring jars in that case. The Velocity classes has been in the spring-context-support module/jar since at least version 2.5.

Comment: Latest POM reference (substitute your Spring version of course)
`<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
</dependency>`

Answer (score 43):

I wanted to add a complete answer.

First, you add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, if you had a custom `VelocityEngineFactory` like this;

```
@Bean
public VelocityEngineFactory velocityEngine(){
    VelocityEngineFactoryBean bean = new VelocityEngineFactoryBean();
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("input.encoding", "UTF-8");
    properties.setProperty("output.encoding", "UTF-8");
    properties.setProperty("resource.loader", "class");
    properties.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
    bean.setVelocityProperties(properties);
    return bean;
}
```

you need to replace it with a bean definition, something like below (in your `@Configuration` class); The below definition lets you to load templates from classpath.

```
@Bean
public VelocityEngine velocityEngine() throws Exception {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("input.encoding", "UTF-8");
    properties.setProperty("output.encoding", "UTF-8");
    properties.setProperty("resource.loader", "class");
    properties.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
    VelocityEngine velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine(properties);
    return velocityEngine;
}
```

Last, use it as: (here `registration.vm` is found on classpath)

```
@Autowired
private VelocityEngine velocityEngine;

public String prepareRegistrationEmailText(User user) {
    VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
    context.put("username", user.getUsername());
    context.put("email", user.getEmail());
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    velocityEngine.mergeTemplate("registration.vm", "UTF-8", context, stringWriter);
    String text = stringWriter.toString();
    return text;
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, thank you, what do you mean by "is found on classpath"?

Answer (score 20):

Regarding the deprecation of VelocityEngineUtils in Spring, the Spring documentation isn't very clear on what to use instead.

It just says:

> Deprecated. Use mergeTemplateIntoString(VelocityEngine, String,
>   String, Map) instead, following Velocity 1.6's corresponding
>   deprecation in its own API.

And to make it more confusing, the link refers back to itself.

Basically it's just saying use Velocity itself.

Here's a description of how you do that..

```
 // instead of a model map, you use a VelocityContext

 VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext();
 velocityContext.put("key1", value1);
 velocityContext.put("key2", value2);

 // the velocityEngine you wired into Spring has a mergeTemplate function
 // you can use to do the same thing as VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplate
 // with the exception that it uses a writer instead of returning a String      

 StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
 velocityEngine.mergeTemplate("templateName.vm", "UTF-8", velocityContext, stringWriter);

 // this is assuming you're sending HTML email using MimeMessageHelper

 message.setText(stringWriter.toString(), true);
```

Comment: this comment has been extremely helpful but I don't see where you add the `Map<String, Object> model` into the template such as in `VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString` which accepts a `model` argument. You're only merging the template content with the context and not the data model.

Comment: Later note for anyone using `VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString` you need to just call `.put()` on your pre-existing data model and add `"date, new DateTool()"` to your pre-existing model. My project's template syntax is slightly different too where variables are preceded with both a `$` character and a `!` character: `$date.format('yyyy-MM-dd', $!application.dateOfBirth)`

Comment: This is the correct answer since quite sometime.

Answer (score 1):

VelocityEngineUtils is deprecated in spring > 3.2

Below dependency will work perfectly

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.18.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

It's recommended to deprecate Velocity altogether and replace with thymeleaf