# Spring5.0.1 VelocityEngineFactoryBean

Tags: spring

Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Class 'org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean' not found
    - Class 'org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean' not found [config set: MyApp/web-
     context]

```
    <bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
  <property name="velocityProperties">
     <value>
      resource.loader=class
      class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
     </value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 7):

Spring has marked Velocity package **org.springframework.ui.velocity** as deprecated in **Spring 4.3** and removed it completely in **Spring 5.0.1** (according to Jürgen Höller, it's because Velocity Framework *"dates back to 2010"*).
Source: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13795.

However, you can still use Velocity 1.7 in Spring 5.0.x Framework.
Just follow the answer of @bekce in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314143/velocityengineutils-has-been-removed-in-spring-3-2-so-what-else-to-use) thread.

Answer (score 5):

As it was mentioned on [VelocityEngineUtils has been removed in Spring 3.2 so what else to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42349956/5962766) you need to have Velocity dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

For XML configs, replace deprecated VelocityEngineFactoryBean with VelocityEngine:

```
<util:properties id="velocityProperties">
  <prop key="resource.loader">class</prop>
  <prop key="class.resource.loader.class">org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader</prop>
</util:properties>

<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine">
  <constructor-arg ref="velocityProperties">
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `VelocityEngineFactoryBean` has been deprecated in Spring 5, and the option is to use `spring-velocity-support` package.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-velocity-support</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

The `velocityEngine` bean can be updated as

```
<bean id="velocityEngine"
    class="org.apache.velocity.spring.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="velocityProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="resource.loader">class</prop>
            <prop key="class.resource.loader.class">
                org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

https://github.com/apache/velocity-engine/tree/master/spring-velocity-support

Answer (score -1):

if the code need **VelocityEngineFactoryBean** class, project  must contains the dependency of spring-context-support and make sure **spring-context-support version should below 5.0.0** because VelocityEngineFactoryBean & VelocityEngineUtils classes deprecated for the 5.0.0 and above versions.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Never mix jars from different version of a framework, that is only a path to weird errors and incompatible contracts.