# NPE when rending velocity template using toolboxConfigLocation for Spring boot+Velocity Project

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, velocity, servlet-3.0

I got an existing SpringMVC+velocty project, and tried to upgrade it to SpringBoot+Velocity, as a dozens of velocty templates here.

First, everything works in my eclipse environment, and I can visit `http://sxu-mvp-p.xxx-qa.com.cn:8888/login` page.

However, when i built the jar using `mvn clean package -Dconf=dev  -Dmaven.test.skip=true` and following exception was thrown

```
2018-09-22 14:42:43.652 [http-nio-8888-exec-3]  INFO com.xxx.monitor.controller.LoginController.login:58 - Hello world org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutViewResolver@35390ee3
2018-09-22 14:42:43.654 [http-nio-8888-exec-3]  INFO com.xxx.monitor.controller.LoginController.login:61 - Receiver a login request: /login
2018-09-22 14:42:43.744 [http-nio-8888-exec-3] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet].log:181 - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityToolboxView.createVelocityContext(VelocityToolboxView.java:113)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityView.renderMergedTemplateModel(VelocityView.java:290)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractTemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractTemplateView.java:167)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.xxx.utils.web.HttpRequestMDCFilter.doFilter(HttpRequestMDCFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
         .......
```

when visiting the login page.

Here are some of my configuration:

```
pom.xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-velocity -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

//Spring-velocity.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd"
       default-autowire="byName">

    <bean id="velocityConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
        <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/vm"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:velocity.properties"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    </bean>

    <bean id="exceptionResolver" class="com.xxx.monitor.ExceptionHandler"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutViewResolver">
        <property name="suffix" value=".vm"/>
        <property name="layoutUrl" value="/WEB-INF/vm/layout/default.vm"/>
        <!-- 使用springMacro、使用servlet的对象 -->
        <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>
        <property name="exposeRequestAttributes" value="true"/>
         <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/vm/" />
         <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutView" />
        <property name="exposeSessionAttributes" value="true"/>
        <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
        <!-- spring的日期格式化 -->
        <property name="dateToolAttribute" value="dateTool"/>
        <property name="toolboxConfigLocation" value="/WEB-INF/velocity-tools.xml"/> 
        <property name="attributesMap">
            <map>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

<!--     <bean id="velocityEngine"
        class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="velocityProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="resource.loader">file</prop>
            <prop key="file.resource.loader.class">
                org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader
            </prop>
            <prop key="file.resource.loader.path">WEB-INF/vm/</prop>
            <prop key="file.resource.loader.cache">false</prop>
        </props>
       </property>
</bean> -->
</beans>

  //velocity-tools.xml
   <toolbox>
    <tool>
        <key>stringUtils</key>
        <scope>application</scope>
        <class>org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils</class>
    </tool>
    <tool>
        <key>dateFormatUtils</key>
        <scope>application</scope>
        <class>org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateFormatUtils</class>
    </tool>
    <tool>
        <key>escapeUtils</key>
        <scope>application</scope>
        <class>org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils</class>
    </tool>
    <tool>
        <key>loginContextHolder</key>
        <scope>application</scope>
        <class>com.xxx.monitor.vo.LoginContextHolder</class>
    </tool>
</toolbox>
```

The directory hierarchy is shown
BOOT-INFO/classes/
               |  spring-velocity.xml
               |  velocity.properties
               |  WEB-INF/
                           | velocity-tools.xml

NPE is thrown when `servletContext.getResourceAsStream(toolboxFile)` in `ServletToolboxManager::getInstance(ServletContext servletContext, String toolboxFile).`

Besides,  controller is:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class LoginController extends BaseController{
   @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        logger.info("Hello world {}", resolver.toString());
        // 展示login页面
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        logger.info("Receiver a login request: {} ", request.getRequestURI());
        LoginContextHolder.clear();
        mav.setViewName("login");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

It looks like something wrong in the configuration, and the `toolboxConfigLocation` is not used, or the path is wrongly configured. 
Can anyone help resolve it and explain why it works in eclipse? 
Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48626714/spring5-0-1-velocityenginefactorybean

Comment: Look like similar issue :http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/21884-exposing-velocity-generic-tool-results-in-nullpointer

Comment: This page is very old, but the exception is the same, and no solution is found there. I tried the  `<property name="toolboxConfigLocation">
         <value>"/WEB-INF/velocity-tools.xml" </value>
       </property>`  but issue is still there.