# What happened with org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean?

Tags: java, spring

I am upgrading the Spring version of an older application. When starting, I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean
```

Regarding [findjar](https://findjar.com/class/org/springframework/ui/velocity/VelocityEngineFactoryBean.html) this class was part of spring-context in earlier version, but not in the latest version. Can anybody give me a hint, what happened with this class?

Can I use something else?

Update: I found a quick&dirty sulution, I copied VelocityEngineFactoryBean, VelocityEngineFactory and SpringResourceLoader from the earlier Spring version. As I am moving the whole application to Spring Boot in the foreseeable future, this is as workaround acceptable for me.

Comment: As far as I know, velocity support has been dropped.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314143/velocityengineutils-has-been-removed-in-spring-3-2-so-what-else-to-use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring has marked Velocity package as deprecated in Spring 4.3 and removed it completely in Spring 5.x.

Alternate, [here](https://github.com/alibaba/spring-velocity-support)

Comment: Only half of what I need, but that's of course not your fault, Mohamed. Thanks!

Comment: Also, packages are deprecated for a reason. So, I strongly suggest you can also deprecate them in your codebase and go for alternates. Velocity isnt going to cut it!