# How to access spring-boot-starter-velocity in spring boot 2.0.6

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have an existing project which is in Spring boot 1.4.2 and now as per requirement I need to update it to Spring boot 2.0.6. I have Vector as part of functionality, but since it is deprecated in 2.x, I am unable to find genuine reference to use it in 2.0.6.

Could someone help us to figure out how to use :

```java
dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-velocity</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

in

```java
<spring-boot.version>2.0.6.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
```

I found few reference on searching but none was genuinely solving.

Answer (score 0):

There is no more support for velocity in Spring 5:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x#removed-packages-classes-and-methods

Either stay with Spring 4 (Spring Boot 1.x) or integrate velocity yourself.

Comment: So is there no workaround to use Velocity in Spring 5 ? I remember reading VelocityEngineUtils is only deprecated & we still can user velocity. So can I use `VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate()` instead of `VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString()` and then convert it to string ?

Comment: For what purpose are you using VeloCity?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Was able to figure out with below link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314143/velocityengineutils-has-been-removed-in-spring-3-2-so-what-else-to-use